# Link from one app to another in Google Play description

Tags: android, google-play

I have two apps in the google play store.  Is it possible to create an http link from one to another in the description of the first?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Google Play descriptions do not support links. You can tell the reader the name of the app, nothing more.

Plus, in any case, your app will come under the "Related Apps" and "More from developer" headings in most cases.

Comment: That's not (or no longer) true. Now most links are recognised. If one is not you can add a <a href="http:/ /your_link.com">Your link</a> tag.

Comment: Some news about links: despite it works and it's been working for 6 years in my app's description, my app just got removed because I was using a <a href=""> tag. So the best we can do now it to write the link as plain text and hope that their URL detection code works...

Answer (score 22):

> Google Play descriptions do not support links.

That not true.
You can add links to other application in google play with `<a>` tag.
For example, link to my app:

```
<a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.ros.android.android_all_sensors_driver">ROS Sensors</a>
```

You can look at my description app how i do it:
[ROS Sensors](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.ros.android.android_all_sensors_driver)

Comment: Seems to work only in the browser. In the Play Store app, the link is not clickable.

Comment: It used to be true and I used that for the last 6 years. But yesterday my app has been removed from the Play Store for using a <a href=""> tag. Please update your answer so that it does not happen to others.

Answer (score 9):

We can provide links in play store description using two methods.

```
<a href="https://www.google.com">Visit Link</a> https://www.google.com
```

**Output in play store app:**
 Visit Link https://www.google.com
**Output in play store website:**
 [Visit Link](https://www.google.com) https://www.google.com

Note :
 The below code will not make any link in play store app

```
Visit Link <a href="https://www.google.com">https://www.google.com</a>
```

Comment: How do you make the link for a different app, such as "Click here for DiffVersionOfApp" with a Google Play Store url? I don't want to actually show the url if possible, just the text? Is that doable? I saw this: but am not sure how to get it work with the text I want: https://thetool.io/2017/how-to-use-html-emoji-googleplay

Comment: It used to be true and I used that for the last 6 years. But yesterday my app has been removed from the Play Store for using a <a href=""> tag. Please update your answer so that it does not happen to others.

Answer (score 1):

If you put full url address in app description (with https protocol, not only www) it will be visible as a link in browser.

eg:
    https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=domain.company.appname

Of course google play links to apps aren't nice so you can use some url converters.

Comment: That is not true here is an example: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.hanoo.dogtraining

Answer (score 1):

[Google has documentated how to properly link within google play to other resources like a store listing, developer page, a search result etc.](https://developer.android.com/distribute/marketing-tools/linking-to-google-play).

> Linking to a store listing
>
> Use the format below to deep-link directly to an app's Store listing page, where users can see the app description, screenshots, reviews and more, and then install it.
>
> To create the link, you need to know the app's fully qualified package name, which is declared in the app's manifest file. The package name is also visible in the Google Play Console.

```
http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=<package_name>
```

> Here's an example:

```
http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.maps
```

Answer (score 0):

A URL of the following form will be converted to a clickable link and will redirect to the address specified in YOUR_URL.

https://www.google.com/url?q=YOUR_URL

eg: https://www.google.com/url?q=https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=domain.company.appname